# How to handle async firebase calls with hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, react-hooks

I'd like to create a hook for adding data to a firestore database.  I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how hooks work, or firestore works, I'm new to both.

Warning:
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Firebase API

```
  createTeam = newTeam => {
    return this.db.collection("teams").add({
      ...newTeam
    });
  };
```

The hook

```
export default function useFetch(action) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function performAction(body) {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setData(null);
      setError(null);
      const data = await action(body);
      setData(data);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return [{ loading, data, error }, performAction];
}
```

Component

```
  const [state, runFetch] = useFetch(db.createTeam);
  const { values, handleChange, isDirty, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      location: ""
    },
    onSubmit({ values }) {
      runFetch(values);
    },
    validate(e) {
      return e;
    }
  });
```

The state.data is never set to the expected response, however, the logging after await in the fetch hook shows that I am receiving the response.  Should I be doing this in useEffect? What is the appropriate way to accomplish this task via hooks/firebase?

Answer (score 1):

See if that works for you.

That's a great idea for a custom hook.

[image]

Working example on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-joliot-ukr1t

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [state, runFetch] = useFetch(mockAPICall);

  function mockAPICall() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Some data from DB!");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Loading: {state.loading ? "True" : "False"}</div>
      <div>Data: {state.data}</div>
      <button onClick={() => runFetch(mockAPICall)}>Get Data</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function useFetch(action) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function performAction(body) {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setData(null);
      setError(null);
      const data = await action(body);
      setData(data);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return [{ loading, data, error }, performAction];
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```